# call super in subclass created by type

Tags: python, inheritance, dynamic-class-creation

**Update**: made some progress and simplified the example, although I'm currently stumped by the latest error. I have no idea why the `super().__init__` method is unbound.

```
import types

class VeryImportantSuperClass(object):

  def __init__(self, anArg, anotherArg):
    self.anArg = anArg
    #Extremely clever code here

def createSubclassAttempt1(name):
  source = 'def __init__(self, arg):\n' +\
           '  super(' + name + ', self).__init__(arg, 6.02e23)\n' +\
           '  self.foo = self.anArg + 3\n'
  cls = type(name, (VeryImportantSuperClass,), {})
  d = {name: cls}
  exec source in d
  cls.__init__ = types.MethodType(d['__init__'], cls)
  return cls

if __name__ == '__main__':
  cls = createSubclassAttempt1('Foo')
  cls('foo')
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/newb/eclipseWorkspace/TestArea/subclassWithType.py", line 27, in <module>
    cls('foo')
  File "<string>", line 2, in __init__
TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with Foo instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

There's got to be some way to call a superclass method from a subclass created by type, but I'm dashed if I can see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work and do what you want. The`self.foo = self.anArg + 3`statement had to be changed to`self.foo = self.anArg + "3"`to avoid a`TypeError`when attempting to concatenate a`str`and an`int` objects which is what happens with a`cls('f00')`call as shown in the code in your question.

```
import types

class VeryImportantSuperClass(object):
    def __init__(self, anArg, anotherArg):
        self.anArg = anArg
        #Extremely clever code here

def createSubclassAttempt1(name):
    source = ('def __init__(self, arg):\n'
              '    super(' + name + ', self).__init__(arg, 6.02e23)\n'
              '    self.foo = self.anArg + "3"\n')
    d = {}
    exec(source, d)
    cls = type(name, (VeryImportantSuperClass,), d)
    d[name] = cls
    return cls

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cls = createSubclassAttempt1('Foo')
    inst = cls('foo')
    print(cls('foo').foo)  # prints "foo3"
```

(Works in both Python 2.7.3 & 3.3)

Comment: Actually - it looks like you're creating a circular reference to the subclass in the subclass's `__dict__` - isn't that undesirable?

Comment: No, there's no circular reference which you can verify with a `print(cls.__dict__)` after it's created by `createSubclassAttempt1()`. Is that why you apparently didn't even up-vote my answer yourself? IMHO, the major reason no one else has done so is primarily because I didn't see your question and post an answer to it until about 3 hours after you asked it, so the other one was the only one there was during that period of time.

Comment: Upvoting slipped my mind, sorry. I think I finally understand what's going on here - the `__init__` function is created in the `d` namespace, and that namespace is copied to `cls`'s `__dict__`. However, the function still sees the names in d, and so the class name must be added (which doesn't modify `cls.__dict__`) so the super call can be resolved.

Comment: Yes, I believe that's how it works -- a closure is created between the class namespace dict passed to `type()` and the contents of the `d` dictionary. One interesting aspect of this approach is that the entire subclass is created on the fly from the code in the source string each time `createSubclassAttempt1()` function is called -- so it could easily be varied each time. Thanks for the up-vote.

Answer (score 4):

Use a closure for `__init__` in the function creating the class:

```
class VeryImportantSuperClass(object):
    def __init__(self, anArg, anotherArg):
        self.anArg = anArg

def CreateSubclass(name):
    def sub__init__(self, arg):
        super(klass, self).__init__(arg, 6.02e23)
        self.foo = self.anArg + 3

    klass = type(name, (VeryImportantSuperClass, ),
                 {'__init__': sub__init__})
    return klass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cls = CreateSubclass('Foo')
    print(cls(3).foo)
```

Comment: A closure is also being used for `klass`.

Comment: If I could accept your and martineau's answer I would, as they both work, but since you've currently got 3 upvotes and martineau has none I guess I'll communistically share the wealth.